# how to terminate ahk script after another app is finished

Tags: google-chrome, bash, script

I have a simple AHK script I use to launch Google Chrome and also remap 2 keys to help me navigate my browser more easily. The script has 2 functions:

- Launch Chrome
- sets the navigation shortcut keys (only when Chrome is in focus)

I'd like to add one more parameter that closes the AHK script once Chrome closed, but unsure of how to do this.

I know I could write a `.bat` script to manage this which would allow me to run a loop with `TASKLIST|FIND` which could ultimately close the script on not finding Chrome, but I dont want to have an extra CMD window taking up space in my taskbar.

I like that AHK can launch the Chrome while also allowing me to set keys, but is it possible to run some kind of command like:

`if chrome is not running, close AHK script`?

EDIT - working off of Harry's answer:

```
RunWait , "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
ExitApp

#IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1

Insert::Send !{Left}
Delete::Send !{Right}
```

**EDIT** - while the code above works wonderfully, the same code with a different path and binary are rejected by AHK:

```
RunWait , "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor.exe"
ExitApp

#IfWinActive, ahk_class UnrealWindow
Shift::MButton
```

This returns the error:

[image]

The path is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the AutoHotkey Run command, use the
[RunWait command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm).

RunWait will wait until the program finishes before continuing, so can be
followed by the
[ExitApp command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Exit.htm)
which terminates the script unconditionally.

Comment: You didn't add `exit` after the RunWait.

Comment: oops yes, but something isnt working still. Updated code

Comment: Place the additional commands immediately after the RunWait, not inside the shortcut definition.

Comment: I dont know what you mean.. What commands are you talking about?  It might be easier if you edited my question.

Comment: Did as you asked.

Comment: This is VERY helpful. I learned a bunch. THank you again!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115561/discussion-between-kalamalka-kid-and-harrymc).

Comment: The error "the svslem cannot f‌ind the file specif‌ied" is self-explanatory. Your path is wrong (likely) or you lack permissions (less likely).

Comment: double checked the path. It is correct. So in this case I need to set permissions for the dir?IT seems I have full permissions.  I am able to launch the binary via .bat, so why not AHK?

Comment: it wont even work with a shortcut

Comment: The error message contains "Binaries\Wîn64]UEdEditor.exe". The **]** should be an anti-slash.

Comment: I saw this too, but when we observe the syntax in the actual script it is in fact an anti-slash. What is going on here might be a bug?

Comment: Everything is possible, but AHK is unlikely to have such a bug.

Comment: I have posted on the AHK forums as to this being a possible bug - https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=82577&p=360388#p360388 - there is no other explanation I can think of why a path would return this error in the process.